# Oracle partitioning recommendations

Tags: oracle, plsql

Due to being locked down by Corona, I don't have easy access to my more knowledgeable colleagues, so I'm hoping for a few possible recommendations here.

We do quarterly and yearly "freezes" of a number of statistical entities with a large number (1-200) of columns. Everyone then uses these "frozen" versions as a common basis for all statistical releases in Denmark. Currently, we simply create a new table for each version.
There's a demand to test if we can consolidate these several hundred tables to 26 entity-based tables to make programming against them easier, while not harming performance too much.

A "freeze" is approximately 1 million rows and consists of: Year + Period + Type + Version.
For example:

2018_21_P_V1 = Preliminary Data for 2018 first quarter version 1

2019_41_F_V2 = Final Data for 2019 yearly version 2

I am simply not very experienced in the world of partitions. My initial thought was to partition on Year + Period and Subpartiton on Type + Version, but I am no longer sure this is the right approach, nor do I have a clear picture of which partitioning type would solve the problem best.

I am hoping someone can recommend an approach as it would help me tremendously and save me a lot of time "brute force" testing a lot of different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current situation which you explained I highly recommend that "USE THE PARTITIONING". No doubt.
It's highly effective and easy to use. You can read Oracle documentation about partitioning or search on the web for that to understand how to start. 
In general, when you partition a table, Oracle looks at each partition as a separate table so don't worry about the speed of fetching data.
The most important step is to choose the best field(s) to establish your partitions based on. I used the date format (20190506) in number or int data type for my daily basis. Or (201907) for a monthly basis. You should design and test it.
 The next is to decide about the sub-partitions. In some cases, you don't really need one. It depends on your data structure and your expectations from the data. What do you want to do with the data? Which fields are more important? (used in where clause, ...) 
Then make some index(es) for each partition. Very important. 
Another important point is that using partitions may have some changes in the way you code in pl/sql. For example, you can not use 2 or more partitions in a single query at the same time. You should select and fetch data from different partitions one by one.
And don't worry about 1 million records. I used partitioning for tables way larger than this and it works fine.
Goodluck